# calculate hours based on business hours in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking to calculate hours between a start and end of time of a task based on business hours. I have the following sample data:

```
TASK | START_TIME | END_TIME
A | 16-JAN-17 10:00 | 23-JAN-17 11:35
B | 18-JAN-17 17:53 | 19-JAN-17 08:00
C | 13-JAN-17 13:00 | 17-JAN-17 14:52
D | 21-JAN-17 10:00 | 30-JAN-17 08:52
```

and I need to work out the difference between the two but based on the following business hours:

```
Mon - Sat 08:00 - 18:00
```

I know how to write the calculation but not sure what I do to add the business hours into the calculation.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What about weekends and public holidays?

Comment: Thanks Wernfried for your response. Saturdays are counted as business hours (08:00 - 18:00), sundays have to be excluded and forgot about public holidays so will need to factor that in for this year.

Comment: How about daylight savings time changes?

Comment: @DavidAldridge Daylight saving setting changes always offside working hours, so it should have no impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly calculate the difference in hours:

```sql
SELECT task,
       start_time,
       end_time,
       ROUND(
         (
           -- Calculate the full weeks difference from the start of ISO weeks.
           ( TRUNC( end_time, 'IW' ) - TRUNC( start_time, 'IW' ) ) * (10/24) * (6/7)
           -- Add the full days for the final week.
           + LEAST( TRUNC( end_time ) - TRUNC( end_time, 'IW' ), 6 ) * (10/24)
           -- Subtract the full days from the days of the week before the start date.
           - LEAST( TRUNC( start_time ) - TRUNC( start_time, 'IW' ), 6 ) * (10/24)
           -- Add the hours of the final day
           + LEAST( GREATEST( end_time - TRUNC( end_time ) - 8/24, 0 ), 10/24 )
           -- Subtract the hours of the day before the range starts.
           - LEAST( GREATEST( start_time - TRUNC( start_time ) - 8/24, 0 ), 10/24 )
         )
         -- Multiply to give minutes rather than fractions of full days.
         * 24,
         15 -- Number of decimal places
       ) AS work_day_hours_diff
FROM   your_table;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table ( TASK, START_TIME, END_TIME ) AS
SELECT 'A', DATE '2017-01-16' + INTERVAL '10:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2017-01-23' + INTERVAL '11:35' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', DATE '2017-01-18' + INTERVAL '17:53' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2017-01-19' + INTERVAL '08:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', DATE '2017-01-13' + INTERVAL '13:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2017-01-17' + INTERVAL '14:52' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', DATE '2017-01-21' + INTERVAL '10:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2017-01-30' + INTERVAL '08:52' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs (with the date format `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS (DY)`):

> ```
> TASK | START_TIME                | END_TIME                  | WORK_DAY_HOURS_DIFF
> :--- | :------------------------ | :------------------------ | ------------------:
> A    | 2017-01-16 10:00:00 (MON) | 2017-01-23 11:35:00 (MON) |  61.583333333333333
> B    | 2017-01-18 17:53:00 (WED) | 2017-01-19 08:00:00 (THU) |    .116666666666667
> C    | 2017-01-13 13:00:00 (FRI) | 2017-01-17 14:52:00 (TUE) |  31.866666666666667
> D    | 2017-01-21 10:00:00 (SAT) | 2017-01-30 08:52:00 (MON) |  68.866666666666667
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d8a83e155c8dc583eda5377915fb56ab)*

---

## Previous solution:

You can use a correlated hierarchical query to generate one row for each work day and then sum the hours for each day:

```
SELECT task,
       COALESCE( SUM( end_time - start_time ), 0 ) * 24 AS total_hours
FROM   (
  SELECT task,
         GREATEST( t.start_time, d.column_value + INTERVAL '8' HOUR ) AS start_time,
         LEAST( t.end_time, d.column_value + INTERVAL '18' HOUR ) AS end_time
  FROM   your_table t
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
         TABLE(
           CAST(
             MULTISET(
               SELECT TRUNC( t.start_time + LEVEL - 1 )
               FROM   DUAL
               WHERE  TRUNC( t.start_time + LEVEL - 1 ) - TRUNC( t.start_time + LEVEL - 1, 'iw' ) < 6
               CONNECT BY TRUNC( t.start_time + LEVEL - 1 ) < t.end_time
             ) AS SYS.ODCIDATELIST
           )
         ) d
         ON (   t.end_time   > d.column_value + INTERVAL  '8' HOUR
            AND t.start_time < d.column_value + INTERVAL '18' HOUR )
)
GROUP BY task;
```

Comment: MT0, apologies, any chance you can explain or add some comments to the code just for my understand. Hope that's ok.

Comment: `SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10` will generate 10 rows - the correlated hierarchical query is just doing the same generating a list of days from the `start_time` to the `end_time` in 1-day increments for each row of your table. The `WHERE` clause in that hierarchical query eliminates Sundays as non-working days.

Comment: The `GREATEST` and `LEAST` find the start and end times for each day within the range and then in the outer-most query the difference between start and end times is totaled for each task.

Comment: Thank you, lastly the d.column_value where is this coming from?

Comment: The `TABLE()` table collection expression generates a table with a single column named `COLUMN_VALUE` - so its an automatically generated column.

Comment: Thank you MT0, works a treat, thank you for the explanation

Comment: MT0, I decided to test the query by adding in values that fall outside the business hours and I can see that this gives me minus figures for my total hours when in fact this should just show 0. The values I tried are '04-APR-16 05:21:33' for start and '04-APR-16 05:24:00' and for end. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3191160 Updated

Comment: MT0, thank you that works a treat. Just been told now that I will have to maybe run this on Hive (Big Data) and most functions aren't available on there so now my job will be to convert this... Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

My favorite of this problem is to use the build-in `SCHEDULER SCHEDULE`.

You have to create a function using [DBMS_SCHEDULER.EVALUATE_CALENDAR_STRING](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm#i1009923)

First, create some schedules for exceptions like public holidays, if required.
Here an example for US bank days:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('NEW_YEARS_DAY', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDATE=0101');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('MARTIN_LUTHER_KING_DAY', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTH=JAN;BYDAY=3 MON', comments => 'Third Monday of January');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('WASHINGTONS_BIRTHDAY', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTH=FEB;BYDAY=3 MON', comments => 'Third Monday of February');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('MEMORIAL_DAY', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTH=MAY;BYDAY=-1 MON', comments => 'Last Monday of May');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('INDEPENDENCE_DAY', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDATE=0704');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('CHRISTMAS_DAY', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDATE=1225');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('SPRING_BREAK', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;BYDATE=0301+SPAN:7D');
END;
```

or another example for German bank days:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('New_Year', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;BYDATE=0101');

    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('Easter_Sunday',  repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;BYDATE=20150405,    20160327,    20170416,    20170416,    20180401,    20190421,    20200412', comments => 'Hard coded till 2020');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('Good_Friday',    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;BYDATE=20150405-2D, 20160327-2D, 20170416-2D, 20170416-2D, 20180401-2D, 20190421-2D, 20200412-2D', comments => '2 Days before Easter');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('Easter_Monday',   repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;BYDATE=20150405+1D, 20160327+1D, 20170416+1D, 20170416+1D, 20180401+1D, 20190421+1D, 20200412+1D', comments => '1 Day after Easter');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('Ascension_Day',   repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;BYDATE=20150405+39D,20160327+39D,20170416+39D,20170416+39D,20180401+39D,20190421+39D,20200412+39D', comments => '39 Days after Easter');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('Pentecost_Monday', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;BYDATE=20150405+50D,20160327+50D,20170416+50D,20170416+50D,20180401+50D,20190421+50D,20200412+50D', comments => '50 Days after easter');

    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('Repentance_and_Prayer', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;BYDATE=1122-SPAN:7D;BYDAY=WED', 
        comments => 'Wednesday before November 23th, Buss- und Bettag');
    -- alternative solution: 
    --DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('Repentance_and_Prayer', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTH=NOV;BYDAY=3 WED', 
    --    comments => '3rd Wednesday in November');

    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('Labor_Day', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;BYDATE=0501');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('German_Unity_Day', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;BYDATE=1003');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('Christmas', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;BYDATE=1225+SPAN:2D');

    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('Christian_Celebration_Days', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;INTERSECT=Easter_Sunday,Good_Friday,Easter_Monday,Ascension_Day,Pentecost_Monday,Repentance_and_Prayer,Christmas');
    -- alternative solution: 
    -- DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('Christian_Celebration_Days', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=Good_Friday;BYDAY=1 MON, 6 THU,8 MON');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('Political_Holidays', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;INTERSECT=New_Year,Labor_Day,German_Unity_Day');

END;
/
```

See syntax for calendar here: [Calendaring Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm#BABFBCEF)

Then create a function similar to this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetBusinessHours(start_time IN TIMESTAMP, end_time IN TIMESTAMP) RETURN INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND AS
    next_run_date TIMESTAMP := start_time;
     duration INTERVAL DAY(3) TO SECOND(0) := INTERVAL '0' HOUR;
BEGIN
    LOOP
        DBMS_SCHEDULER.EVALUATE_CALENDAR_STRING('FREQ=HOURLY;INTERVAL=1;BYHOUR=8,9,10,11,13,14,15,16,17;BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT; EXCLUDE=NEW_YEARS_DAY,MARTIN_LUTHER_KING_DAY,WASHINGTONS_BIRTHDAY,MEMORIAL_DAY,INDEPENDENCE_DAY,CHRISTMAS_DAY,SPRING_BREAK', NULL, next_run_date, next_run_date);
        duration := duration + INTERVAL '1' HOUR;
        EXIT WHEN next_run_date >= end_time;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN duration;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetBusinessStart(start_time IN TIMESTAMP, end_time IN TIMESTAMP) RETURN TIMESTAMP AS
    next_run_date TIMESTAMP := start_time;
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.EVALUATE_CALENDAR_STRING('FREQ=HOURLY;INTERVAL=1;BYHOUR=8,9,10,11,13,14,15,16,17;BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT; EXCLUDE=NEW_YEARS_DAY,MARTIN_LUTHER_KING_DAY,WASHINGTONS_BIRTHDAY,MEMORIAL_DAY,INDEPENDENCE_DAY,CHRISTMAS_DAY,SPRING_BREAK', NULL, next_run_date, next_run_date);
    RETURN next_run_date;
END;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetBusinessEnd(start_time IN TIMESTAMP, end_time IN TIMESTAMP) RETURN TIMESTAMP AS
    next_run_date TIMESTAMP := start_time;
BEGIN
    LOOP
        DBMS_SCHEDULER.EVALUATE_CALENDAR_STRING('FREQ=HOURLY;INTERVAL=1;BYHOUR=8,9,10,11,13,14,15,16,17;BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT; EXCLUDE=NEW_YEARS_DAY,MARTIN_LUTHER_KING_DAY,WASHINGTONS_BIRTHDAY,MEMORIAL_DAY,INDEPENDENCE_DAY,CHRISTMAS_DAY,SPRING_BREAK', NULL, next_run_date, next_run_date);
        EXIT WHEN next_run_date >= end_time;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN next_run_date;
END;
```

If you don't have to consider pubic holidays, just skip `EXCLUDE=...` part.

Then you can use the function in your query:

```
SELECT TASK, 
   GetBusinessStart(START_TIME, END_TIME),
   GetBusinessEnd(START_TIME, END_TIME),
   GetBusinessHours(START_TIME, END_TIME)
FROM ...;
```

Note, the function would need some fine-tuning in case START_TIME and END_TIME fall both into the same non-working day.