# Is it possible to Insert appointment date by interval of daily/weekly/monthly

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

## Insert  appointment date by interval of daily/weekly/monthly

I am new in Apex and I want to do an insert for the follow up doctor visit with intervals of daily/weekly/monthly appointments.

How should I write this query? Loop? Or is it better to do a pl/sql procedure/function?
Can you make an example?

What I want to do :

1. Select a start date
2. select number of time for the appointments
3. Select interval
4. Insert/generate appointments automatically in a table

Example :

- ***Start date*** : 26-05-2015 (let's suppose 26 is a monday)
- ***Number of appointments*** : 3
- ***Interval*** : if **daily**( appointments in the next 3 days (27/28/29) ; if **weekly** (appointments every monday for the next 3 weeks) , if **monthly** (appointment every 26 of the month for the next 3 months)
- press confirm/save/insert in the apex app form and insert in database table.

Comment: You may use the Oracle calendar Syntax, see this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/41937356/3027266

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How should I write this query?

You can use a hierarchical query:

```
INSERT INTO table_name ( appointment_date )
SELECT CASE :interval_type
       WHEN 'daily'
       THEN :start_date + INTERVAL '1' DAY * LEVEL
       WHEN 'weekly'
       THEN :start_date + INTERVAL '7' DAY * LEVEL
       WHEN 'monthly'
       THEN ADD_MONTHS( :start_date, LEVEL )
       END
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY
       LEVEL <= :number_of_appointments
```

*sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3cf7479/6)*