# DBMS_SCHEDULER next run date

Tags: oracle, oracle19c, dbms-scheduler

Good day.
A little background ...
There was an Oracle 12.2 database.
It used the DBMS_JOBS packages and used the expression
dbms_job.next_date (job, nvl (datetime, sysdate));
Recently migrated DB to Oracle 19
Please tell me how in DBMS_SCHEDULER the next start of the job appears?
Is it possible to update the date of the next launch, substituting the date in the format 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24: MI: SS' from a previously prepared table or from a function that determines when it is necessary to start a job?

Answer (score 2):

In DBMS_SCHEDULER you can create even complex schedule times, see example [calculate hours based on business hours in Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936398/calculate-hours-based-on-business-hours-in-oracle-sql/41937356#41937356)

How do you run `dbms_job.next_date`? Perhaps instead of setting the start time of your job, just execute the job manually with `DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB(job_name, FALSE);`.

Or create a Scheduler Job without start time

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB
    (
       job_name        => '<job_name>'
      ,start_date      => NULL
      ,repeat_interval => NULL
      ,end_date        => NULL
      ,job_class       => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS'
      ,job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK'
      ,job_action      => '<PL/SQL procedure>'
    );
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE
    ( NAME      => '<job_name>'
     ,attribute => 'AUTO_DROP'
     ,VALUE     => FALSE);
END;
```

And then set the start time when you like to run it:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE
    ( name      => '<job_name>'
     ,attribute => 'START_DATE'
     ,value     => TIMESTAMP '2021-11-05 12:30:00');
END;
```

Just another note, a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` does not have any format as such. The values are stored as internal byte values, what you see is the (default) output format according to current session `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` / `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`. You should **never** store date/time values as string, it's a design flaw.

If you just like to know, when your jobs runs the next time, run this query:

```
SELECT JOB_NAME, START_DATE, END_DATE, LAST_START_DATE, NEXT_RUN_DATE
FROM ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS
WHERE JOB_NAME = '<job_name>';
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there's no `next_date` there. Scheduler uses (as [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72235) says)

> rich **calendaring syntax** to enable you to define repeating schedules, such as "every Tuesday and Friday at 4:00 p.m." or "the second Wednesday of every month." This calendaring syntax is used in calendaring expressions in the repeat_interval argument of a number of package subprograms.

According to that, I'm not sure you can easily "convert" dates stored in your table into such a *calendar*.

You could, though, schedule a job that runs only once, at a time fetched from your table, and use it as scheduler's `start_date` parameter.

Comment: There was an idea to create a separate job and update START_DATE, but as far as I understand this is not entirely correct ..

Comment: BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE ('DBMS_JOB$_'||svc.get_setting('PLANNER_JOB'),'start_date',to_date(app_plan.svc.get_setting('PLANNER_NEXT_TIME'),'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable('DBMS_JOB$_'||svc.get_setting('PLANNER_JOB'));

END;

Answer (score 0):

As a result, I did the following: Created, in which the time of the next job start is picked up from the tuning table.

```html
 
.....................
    declare
    planner_time DATE :=to_date(app_plan.svc.get_setting('PLANNER_NEXT_TIME'),'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
.....................        
        IF SYSDATE> = planner_time
    THEN
    dbms_scheduler.run_job (job_name => JOB_NAME || PLANNER_ID);
    END IF;
.....................
```

And I put this procedure in a new job that runs every 2 minutes