# Oracle Scheduler Jobs - Interval Functions

Tags: oracle

hoping someone can help, I'm in the process of changing our DBMS_JOBS into DBMS_SCHEDULER jobs. Currently our DBMS_JOB uses a function for the INTERVAL, this function queries a table with a list of run times and returns the next time from SYSDATE. The times are not evenly spread out throughout the day, so it wouldn't quite work using something like 'FREQ=HOURLY'.

I can't find anything similar to do this for a Scheduler Job. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance :)

```
-- DBMS_JOB
INTERVAL = stk_HHD.SetNext

--Interval Function
FUNCTION SetNext
    RETURN  DATE
IS
    PfldNext    DATE;
BEGIN

    SELECT MIN(MOD(MOD(transfer-SysDate,1)+1,1))+SysDate INTO PfldNext
      FROM stk_Schedule
     WHERE source = 'HHD'
    ;

    RETURN NVL(PfldNext,TRUNC(SysDate,'MI')+1);

END SetNext;

-- Data
SOURCE TRANSFER          
------ ------------------
HHD    01-APR-08 02:45:00
HHD    01-APR-08 06:45:00
HHD    01-APR-08 08:15:00
HHD    01-APR-08 09:45:00
HHD    01-APR-08 11:15:00
HHD    01-APR-08 12:45:00
HHD    01-APR-08 14:15:00
HHD    01-APR-08 15:45:00
HHD    01-APR-08 17:15:00
```

Edit: more details added.

Comment: Yes the calendar syntax is quite powerful see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936398/calculate-hours-based-on-business-hours-in-oracle-sql/41937356#41937356 but you need to give more details for any answer

Comment: Added some more details of existing code for the function

Comment: What is the purpose of `MOD(..., 1)`? It just returns the input value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DBMS_SCHEDULER` jobs support the legacy `DBMS_JOB` interval syntax. While they have a newer more powerful syntax available, the legacy works perfectly well and for those used to it may be simpler to work with (I find that to be the case myself).

As for calling a function, that works too:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_my_repeat_interval
  RETURN date
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN SYSDATE + 30/1440; -- whatever logic you need
END;

BEGIN
  dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name=>'TESTJOB',
                            job_type=>'PLSQL_BLOCK',
                            job_action=>'BEGIN NULL; END;', -- just for testing
                            repeat_interval => 'f_my_repeat_interval',
                            enabled => TRUE);
END;
```

This works fine, at least in 19c. It dynamically executes the `repeat_interval` code which fires a function and returns a date, and that becomes the next run date.

Comment: This worked, I had no idea legacy syntax worked - no idea why I didn't try it! I'm sure I didn't find it any any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an event based scheduler job can solve your issue.

Example details are given on the link below.

```
-- add an event queue subscriber for this user's messages
exec dbms_scheduler.add_event_queue_subscriber('crcagent')

-- create the first job and have it raise an event whenever it completes
-- (succeeds, fails or stops),
-- (Not anymore :in this case it should fail with an error due to lack of ";" at the end of the insert statement
begin
dbms_scheduler.create_job
( 'first_job', job_action =>
'insert into job_output values(systimestamp, ''first job runs'');',
job_type => 'plsql_block',
enabled => false, repeat_interval=>'freq=secondly;interval=30' ) ;
dbms_scheduler.set_attribute
( 'first_job' , 'raise_events' , dbms_scheduler.job_run_completed);
end;
/

-- create a procedure that retrieves the status of first_job from the message
create or replace procedure second_proc
(message IN sys.scheduler$_event_info) as
msg_text varchar2(4000);
begin
-- compose the message
msg_text :=
'Job: "'||message.object_owner||'"."'||message.object_name||'"
Event: '|| message.event_type || '
Date: '|| regexp_replace(message.event_timestamp,'\.[0-9]{3,}') || '
Error code: ' || message.error_code|| '
Error message:
' || message.error_msg;

-- insert into job output
insert into job_output values (systimestamp,
'first_job has completed, status is '||msg_text);
end;
/

-- create a program that the second job runs, so we can get the status of
-- the first job using a metadata argument
begin
dbms_scheduler.create_program (
program_name => 'second_prog',
program_action=> 'second_proc',
program_type => 'stored_procedure',
number_of_arguments => 1,
enabled => FALSE) ;

dbms_scheduler.define_metadata_argument (
'second_prog','event_message',1);

dbms_scheduler.enable('second_prog');
end;
/


-- create the second job that runs whenever the first job completes
begin
dbms_scheduler.create_job('second_job',
program_name => 'second_prog',
event_condition =>
'tab.user_data.object_name = ''FIRST_JOB''',
queue_spec =>'sys.scheduler$_event_queue,crcagent',
enabled=>true);
end;
/

-- finally enable the first_job so it starts running
exec dbms_scheduler.enable('first_job')
```

[Event Based Job Example](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/1431664_1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the schedule you provided, you could create two schedules and combine them

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('s1', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;BYHOUR=2,6,9,12,15;BYMINUTE=45');

DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('s2', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;BYHOUR=8,11,14,17;BYMINUTE=15');

DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('s3', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERSECT=s1,s2');

END;
/
```

Then you can use this schedule in your job.

Comment: Interesting about combining schedule like that, didn't know that was possible. This is still an option but ideally I'd like to use the function in case the values in the table change.